# How to convert a text file to xml using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

**I have a text file which looks like below.
File will not have any headers**

```
AAAA|XXX|1111|2222|         |111GGGGGG342||
BBBB|YYY|3333|4444|         |222NNNNNN565||
CCCC|ZZZ|5555|6666|         |333XXXXXX834||
Some unwanted lines below
```

**I need to convert it into a xml file like below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input>
  <item>
     <data1>AAAA</data1>
     <data2>XXX</data2>
     <data3>1111</data3>
     <data4>2222</data4>
     <data5>111GGGGGG342</data5>
  </item>
</input>
<input>
  <item>
     <data1>BBBB</data1>
     <data2>YYY</data2>
     <data3>3333</data3>
     <data4>4444</data4>
     <data5>222NNNNNN565</data5>
  </item>
</input>
<input>
  <item>
     <data1>CCCC</data1>
     <data2>ZZZ</data2>
     <data3>5555</data3>
     <data4>6666</data4>
     <data5>333XXXXXX834</data5>
  </item>
</input>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].  SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Hey @mzjn, Forgive me im a newbie. I didn't even know how to create certain xml tags and then add the data to the respective tags from my text file.

Comment: There is no shame in being a newbie. We just expect you to do some research and try something yourself before posting.

Comment: That's cent percent right, i did some research, tried to understand and felt what i was doing is completely wrong/inappropriate and no point in sharing here. Will try harder this time for the sake of @Nic3500. Thanks mzjn

Comment: To get you started.  **1** read each line of your input file.  **2** split this line into it's elements.  Here the data fields.  **3** for your XML, simply print it's content, building the data values with what you read prior.  **4** remember XML is simply a formatted text file, so you do not need a complex parser - builder to generate one.  Your case is somewhat simple, so do not overdo it.  If you get more complex operations later, then you can invest the time to learn a complete XML parser - editor.

Comment: So you need: how to open a file and read each line.  Split each line on the `|` character.  How to create a new line of text.  How to print each line into your output file.  Users on SO will help with specific situations, but not train you on python from the start.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500 for your time and inputs, will give it a try.

Comment: I wrote a basic process and code example for you.  It's close to what you need but likely needs some tweaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is effectively:

1. Set up root then input sub tree
2. Open CSV using | as the delimiter
3. Iterate through the rows in the file and remove any data that is blank
4. Create input sub tree per row
5. Iterate through the items in the row and add as a sub element
6. Write the XML out to a file

Try something like this:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element("root") # set up root
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "input") # set up input

with open('input.csv') as csv_file: # import csv file
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|') # split the file using the | as a delimiter
    for row in csv_reader: # iterate through each row in the file
        blanks_removed_row = ' '.join(row).split() # remove any row in the file that is empty (I've assumed you needed this as the output didn't have blank data)
        input = ET.SubElement(doc, "item") # create an item 
        for i, item in enumerate(blanks_removed_row, start=1): # iterate through each row item and enumerate (to start counting from 1)
            ET.SubElement(input, "data{0}".format(i)).text = item # insert a new data element with the item appending the count number to the data

tree = ET.ElementTree(root) 
tree.write("filename.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True) # save tree
```

Comment: Hi @Johny John Boy, this met all my requirements. Thanks for your time and effort. Really appreciate it.